# Opening XE7 project in 10.1 Berlin - all of the objects are differently scaled and positioned

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am trying to edit a 3D app project, written in XE7, on RAD Studio Berlin. It's a simple 3D app with a few dummy objects and a few meshes.

When I load the project, all of the objects are differently scaled and positioned than in XE7, objects are much smaller and repositioned. When I edit the scale, position and rotation variables, I can get similar results, but that's not the solution.

To simplify, I'd like to know how to open my XE7 3D project in RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin.

Comment: @Dalija: I think it is pretty clear what he is asking: "Why does my 3D project created in XE7 look totally differently when I open it in 10.1 Berlin?". I assume that in the meantime, FMX must have changed, but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: @Rudy: I assume the same, subquestion would be, what has changed in 3D FMX

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Obviously something changed. But it is hard to say what. Without proper MCVE we can only guess or try blindly and maybe trigger the same issue or maybe not.

Comment: @JustinCase: but it might make sense to write a very simple [mcve] that displays the problem, so others can reproduce the problem and find an answer.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: did you know that `[mcve]` in a comment expands to the link? There are more, similar shortcuts in S.O.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I knew it probably does but was not sure, so I used full link  instead.

Comment: @Rudy: It has nothing to do with the codding, when you drag/drop model3d on a 3D form, it is different then inXE7

Comment: @Justin: So either something in FMX changed, or in the designer.

Comment: @Rudy:My guess the same

Comment: Instead of an MCVE, a few simple steps would do as well, e.g. "Create a new xyz project, drop an abc on it, set rotation to bla, etc.". Just edit your question and add such a number of steps. Use the icons above the editor to format your list.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't careful enough (read:at all) so I've missed to see new property of Model3D object called WrapMode. It is set to FIT by default, switching to ORIGINAL solves the problem (which really isn't :) ). Big thanks to Rudy Velthuis and Dalija Prasnikar for the effort!